# How to update only once even when user refreshes page the page again?

Tags: php

I want to update only once even when the user refreshes the page many times.How can I do that?

**updateunblockedbooks.php**

```
if($quantbuy<=$quantity){
    $upd="update books set quantity=quantity-'$quantbuy' where code='$code' ";
    mysqli_query($con,$upd);
}
```

**HTML form page**

```
<form name="updatebook" action="updateunblockedbooks.php" method="get">
quantity:<br/><input type="number" name="quantbuy" id="quantity" required><br/>
Code:<br/><input type="number" name="code" id="code"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate2();"><br/>
```

Is using header after updating a good idea for my question?

Comment: redirect page to same page after update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to that page where this form is filled from or you can redirect to a thank you page and you can also send some message to the redirection page and according to that message value you can display success or error message so the person filling the form knows what happened.

So redirect like this:

```
header("location:redirection-page-name.php?msg=success");
```

And on the page where this redirects to get that msg and display message.

Answer (score 1):

you should redirect your page after update

like this

```
header('Location:whaterever_your_page.php');
```

Comment: How do you control that he only redirects only one time after update and not each time the user refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the "Post-Redirect-Get" pattern. In addition, you'd better change your form method to post.

Answer (score 0):

Use one more column in books table like is up_dated and set default value like 0 and after update first time set up_dated to 1. And check it before update the book table if up_dated=0 then update books otherwise not.